# Angular material separate md-tabs body

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular material (https://material.angularjs.org/)

Is there a way to separate a tabs body from the tab list? I couldn't find any mention of this in the documentation.

Currently I have something like this, I need to move `md-tab-body` outside of `md-tabs`. Preferably without use of states or controller show/hide logic.

```
<md-tabs>
<md-tab>
    <md-tab-label>First tab</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
        <p>First tabs content.</p>
    </md-tab-body>
</md-tab>
<md-tab>
    <md-tab-label>Second tab</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
        <p>Second tabs content.</p>
    </md-tab-body>
</md-tab>
```

Comment: No, it's not possible ; it would have absolutely no sense. If your goal is purely aesthetic, why don't you simply use CSS?

Comment: @Blackhole I didnt mean literally move the `md-tab-body` out; just achieving the same effect within the framework itself without extra bloat, since its possible in, for example, bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't currently possible, but there may be different solutions depending on your use-case.

## Option 1

The `md-tab-body` is optional, so you can use `md-tabs` to only handle the tab bar, and manually handle your tab content elsewhere, bound to the same selected index used by `md-tabs`.

## Option 2

A lot of people want this functionality so that the tab bar can be a part of `md-toolbar`.  This can be achieved by putting the `md-tabs` element directly after the `md-toolbar`, as demonstrated here: http://codepen.io/robertmesserle/pen/LVxzNW